# How to Use HDFS Intra-DataNode Disk Balancer in Apache Hadoop 2?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We use Hadoop 2.7.3. HDFS Disk Balancer is a new feature for Hadoop3.  What is the best alternative way to do HDFS Disk balancer in Hadoop2?

Answer (score 0):

Not a really orthodox way to do it, but you could try forcing the namenode to invalidate the blocks stored on the un-balanced datanode stopping it and waiting until the under-replicated counts rises. After they have been replicated, you can start again the datanode and run the hdfs balancer if necessary. Hope it helps